# Check If ID row exists, if not then create it

Tags: c#, mysql

I've researched through the website to find an answer for this and most of them are close to my question but it only looks for a row in specific. I want to put the default ID as 1 but say that row is already being used I want it to search through the rows till it creates a new row with a new ID. **Would  I have to make my ID a unique index?**

Example: (search column until it can create a row)

```
ID (PK, AI)
(row 1) ID: 1   admin
(row 2) ID: 2   guest
(row 3) ID: 3   user
(row 4) *id is not created so create*
```

**tables**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `access` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hwid` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
  `pcname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `info` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'None',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `keys` (
  `key` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log` (
  `Date` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `UID` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `IP` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Action` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**I've also tried to omit the ID column**

```
public MySqlDataReader InsertInto(string tableName, string[] values)
        {
            string query = "";
            try
            {
                query = "INSERT INTO `" + tableName + "` (username, password, access, hwid, ip, pcinfo, info) VALUES(" + "'" + values[0] + "'";
                for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; ++i)
                    query += ", '" + values[i] + "'";
                    query += ")";
            }
            catch { }
            return ExecuteQuery(query);
        }
```

Comment: The point of an ID is for its uniqueness,  so yes it needs to be unique. It does not,  however,  need to be set to auto increment.

Comment: @aguertin Yes I know but the only way I can send the INSERT TO query to the database is in a string and I can't do that but I'll check unique.

Comment: Just to be clear,  all primary keys are unique

Comment: just use AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: @e4c5 Please read what I tagged aguertin in.

Comment: What you are intending to discuss is whether or not it is auto-incremented or not,  which pertains to whether or not you need to specify which row/id it is to be inserted into

Comment: and your point is what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but yes ID column should be unique (based on your requirement) and so thus you need make `ID` either a **primary key** or **unique key**. Which will make sure that your ID values are not repeated and are unique.

You can make it a `auto_increment` column to make sure that ID value gets incremented automatically on every insert but that's not a mandate though.

From you posted table definition I see your `ID` column is already marked as PK and it's `auto_increment` column as pointed below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

With that, you can write your `INSERT` statement as

```
insert into `accounts`(`username`,`password`,`access`,`hwid`,`ip`,`pcname`,`info`)
 values('bla','bla',1,'bla','bla','bla','bla');
```

Comment: I know but the only way I can send the INSERT query is in a string and an INT does not accept a string.

Comment: @PunishSulky, ok ... still fine. read the answer/comments properly. you can define the ID column as `auto_increment` and so don't need to include the ID column in your insert statement.

Comment: @PunishSulky Check your table and make sure ID is the primary key and is not NULL.  This answer is valid based on your requirement

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1AWENeZ.png , it is selected and when I do not include ID in the insert in the INSERT query it says column count does not match count and so then I have to include the ID.

Comment: @PunishSulky, do post your complete table structure. not as pic but as text.

Comment: @Rahul I indeed believe it works but my INSERT statements are in a class and I can't use username.Text on it since it's made in the class so I need to figure out a way to work that out. I'm marking your answer as correct, thank you.

Comment: @PunishSulky, ok .. you can consider posting a new question with this table structure along with your class structure as well. All necessary information which will help people to understand your issue better. example: have no idea when you say *INSERT statements are in a class and I can't use username.Text on it since it's made in the class...*. So consider providing all necessary information